# Eclipse not recognizing passing an extended generic class

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

In my project I have an abstract custom object:

```
public abstract class CustomObject {
    //abstract class goodness
}
```

In another class I am using a few different classes that extend CustomObject and am writing a method that can take the specific class that extends it as a parameter, populates the common fields, and spits it back out as the result.

The method looks like this right now:

```
public <T> T setCommonProperties( Class<T extends CustomObject> clazz, Identifier ident ) {
    CustomObject populate = clazz.newInstance();
    //populate populate
}
```

This looks correct with what I have found while searching the internet, but eclipse marks the `extends` as incorrect. It gives me `Syntax error on token "extends", , expected` when I hover over the extends.

Does anyone have any idea why eclipse may be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Java error; Eclipse is correctly marking it as an error.  Your code has incorrect Java generics syntax.  The `extends` upper bound belongs on the declaration at the beginning, not on the use of the type parameter.  Try

```
public <T extends CustomObject> T setCommonProperties( Class<T> clazz, Identifier ident )
```

Comment: Okay, this seems to work. I kept seeing examples where the extends were in the parameter. Just to clarify you have to use the `extends` the first time `T` is used regardless of location in the code. Is that correct?

Comment: For generic classes, declare the generic type parameter with the class name, e.g. `class GenericClass<T extends CustomObject>` or even `class GenericClass<T extends CustomObject> implements CustomInterface<T>`.  With generic methods, declare the type parameter before the return type as in my answer.